# Code is very slow, is there a better way of doing this?

Tags: typescript, performance, random

I'm making a game, but it's very slow and sometimes even stops because of how slow it is.
This is the code, this is for `Molds` only, there are raritites, qualities, etc. Way more stuff, and they are all done in this same way, is there a way I can make this code faster?

```
  async RandomMold(Mold: string, Embed: MessageEmbed, message: Message) {
    if (
      await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(8803062364500000000000, message)
    ) {
      Mold = Molds.soulstone;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (
      await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(1303062364500000000000, message)
    ) {
      Mold = Molds.mythril;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (
      await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(203062364500000000000, message)
    ) {
      Mold = Molds.aquamarine;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (
      await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(30802364500000000000, message)
    ) {
      Mold = Molds.ammolite;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (
      await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(4667364500000000000, message)
    ) {
      Mold = Molds.quartz;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (
      await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(707364500000000000, message)
    ) {
      Mold = Molds.volcanic;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (
      await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(1072364500000000000, message)
    ) {
      Mold = Molds.azure;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (
      await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(162364500000000000, message)
    ) {
      Mold = Molds.painite;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (
      await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(24596450000000000, message)
    ) {
      Mold = Molds.fossil;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (
      await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(3724645000000000, message)
    ) {
      Mold = Molds.topaz;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(5646450000000, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.moonstone;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(855500000000, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.bloodstone;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(1296450000000, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.crystal;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(196450000000, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.sulfur;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(297500000000, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.uranium;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(45080000000, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.opal;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(6450000000, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.diamond;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(801456019, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.amethyst;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(102891786, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.ruby;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(13673213, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.emerald;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(1882668, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.sapphire;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(6145, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.gold;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(985.87, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.silver;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
      Embed.setDescription(`You got a rare item! Mold: ${Mold}`);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(164.81, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.copper;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(28.75, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.bronze;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
    } else if (await this.bot.functions.RandomChance(28.75, message)) {
      Mold = Molds.stone;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
    } else {
      Mold = Molds.wood;
      Embed.addField("Mold", Mold, true);
    }
    return Mold;
  }
```

Comment: Stop using async/await (for small amounts of work it can easily halve performance compared to a normal function call that does the same work). Then stop using branches (e.g. use something like `x = random_number(); mold = table[x];` where rare molds only have 1 entry and common molds might have 1000 entries). Then stop using Javascript.

Comment: I'm actually using Typescript @Brendan, Thanks for the suggestions.